# How to connect two dynamic IP computers through SSH via a public server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I have a PC at home and a notebook that I use in college, both of them connect to the internet with dynamic IPs. I was trying to figure out how to connect both through an SSH tunnel using a server hosted at AWS with a public static IP.
I tried this method:
First from my notebook:
`ssh -R 2000:localhost:2001 root@awsserver`
, then from my pc:
`ssh -L 2001:localhost:2002 root@awsserver`
and finally at my notebook (expecting to access my PC):
`ssh localhost -p 2000`.
But ssh prompts `connection refused`.
How could I handle this connection?

Comment: Use `-R` where you have `-L` and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

`ssh -R 2000:localhost:2001 root@awsserver` exposes your local port 2001 to remote port 2000 at the aws server. However, when you run `ssh -L 2001:localhost:2002`, you try to map remote's "localhost:2002" to your local 2001 port. That fails, because the remote server doesn't have 2002 port enabled.

The right way how to expose your desktop through the AWS server would be:

- run `ssh -R 2002:localhost:2001 root@awsserver` from your desktop (replace 2001 with whatever your SSH port is; the default is 22; this maps your local port 2001 to remote server's 2002)
- run `ssh -L 2002:localhost:2002` at notebook (this maps remote's 2002 port to your local 2002 port)
- run `ssh -p 2002 localhost` to get the ssh (this connects to your local 2002 port)

Hope it helps :).